# python script for robust multi-array average on microarray data

Tags: python, arrays, bioinformatics, dna-sequence

I have tried google with no luck. I have seen some weak references to robust multi-array averaging done with python but no code. I am not so interested in reinventing the wheel. Any suggestions on a python module, script ....

If I could find a nice explanation or example of the algorithm I would write a python implementation to share.

If you are not sure what I am talking about you could look at this although this is not the definition.
http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/bioinfo/ref/gcrma.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider using a python interface for R, which has gcrma packages for it. [RPy](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/) is a module that allows you to use all R modules installed on your system. [Bioconductor](http://www.bioconductor.org/) has a [gcrma module](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/bioc/html/gcrma.html) for R. I couldn't find any modules for Python that do this.

Comment: Not super interested in using R. I am kinda a STATA fan. Actually I would like to see the actual algorithm used. This is not so easy to find. I would port it over to python if I could find it.

Answer (score 4):

Even though this question was asked more than six years ago, when I asked myself the same question recently, I still couldn't find a good Python implementation of RMA. I therefore did a bunch of research into the methodology and wrote one myself:

- GitHub: https://github.com/flo-compbio/pyaffy

I also wrote an article about it that goes into some technical detail:

[pyAffy: An efficient Python/Cython implementation of the RMA method for processing raw data from Affymetrix expression microarrays](https://peerj.com/preprints/1790/)

Comment: That's great. I ended up doing the same, but didn't open source it as the quality of the code was low. I now know that open sourcing it is a way to improve the code.

Answer (score 0):

I am a biologist working in genomics and contributed to 5-6 microarray projects. I am also quite fluent in Python and can make do pretty well in R.

Python is a great language, but as of now, I am aware of no module that would suite your request easily. R, on the other hand, offers a large gamut of packages for microarray analysis.

Given how microarray data analysis is driven by medical use of standard microarray chips/technologies, biological research has had to use custom developed (mostly R) packages for analysis purposes. Unfortunately, I believe that this situation has left a not so interesting niche for microarray data analysis in more full-fledged programming languages, which are not as appreciated by the crowd of research students.

Hope you do find a python alternative, in which case, please let us know!

Cheers